# string to substring conversion in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, split, substring

```
{"segments":    
    [
        {
            "Group":0,
            "Carrier":"TK",
            "FlightNumber":"###",
            "ChangeOfPlane":false,
            "OptionalServicesIndicator":false,
            "FlownSegment":false,
            "ScheduleChange":false,
            "Origin":"LHR",
            "Destination":"IST",
            "DepartureTime":"2016-04-12T16:30:00.000+01:00",
            "ArrivalTime":"2016-04-12T22:20:00.000+03:00"
        }
        {
            "Group":0,
            "Carrier":"TK",
            "FlightNumber":"118",
            "ChangeOfPlane":false,
            "OptionalServicesIndicator":false,
            "FlownSegment":false,
            "ScheduleChange":false,
            "Origin":"IST",
            "Destination":"KHI",
            "DepartureTime":"2016-04-13T00:10:00.000+03:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the structure what i want is this string "DepartureTime":"2016-04-12T16:30:00.000+01:00" into this format "21 Apr 04:40" 
can anyone help me in this i am new to angular js  and i want to have a filter that can convert my string to my desire result.
Many Thanks

Comment: Can you format your question so that it is more readable? Your question seems to actually be _"given string x, how does one convert it to string y?"_ http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You basically want to parse the date right?

Comment: yes i want this "2016-04-13T00:10:00.000+03:00" string to convert into
"13 Apr 00:10" this using angular js filter so that when i call departuretime with the filter it can convert my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this in your scope

```
var s = "2016-04-13T00:10:00.000+03:00"; //DepartureTime
$scope.v = {
    Dt: s
}
```

and in your html with filter

```
Angular: {{v.Dt | date:'dd MMMM HH:mm'}} <br />
```

**Updated**: Parse your json, based on what you have written in comments

in your ctrl

```
var m = yourJson; 
$scope.items = m.segments;
```

in your html

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.DepartureTime}}</li>
```

and now you can use the filter

Comment: Best answer so far, but I think it could look more professional without that "bro" and focus more on the filter explanation (OP might already have his date in-scope ; or maybe he might need to convert it before display for some reason)

Comment: the web service returns me $scope.segments where in my view i use ng-repeat and use {{ d.DepartureTime}} so what you have done is exactly i want to do but the thing is how to access the array string like 'DepartureTime' and use that filter. there may be many arrays and each contain such string
manythanks @EzequielGonzálezGarcía

Comment: @resume you need to make this var m = yourJson; $scope.items = m.segments;     in your html <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.DepartureTime}}</li>

Answer (score 1):

I advice that you use someone else's code for this like edrian said (moment.js really is amazing).

However, if you want to do this by yourself, in native javascript, you need to parse the date yourself. You can refer to [Mozilla's developer Date page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) where you'll find information on how to work with the date.

I've built a small jsfiddle for you that does exactly what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/ruwqmd2u/

You can see that I'm parsing the whole code line by line after creating a date with your date, while calling a function to deal with the month name:

```
var myDate = new Date("2016-04-12T16:30:00.000+01:00");

// Parse the date
var day = myDate.getDay();
var month = getMonthName(myDate.getMonth());
var hours = myDate.getHours();
var mins = myDate.getMinutes();

// Get a month name from number
function getMonthName(number) {
    if (number===1) return "Jan";
    if (number===2) return "Feb";
    if (number===3) return "Mar";
    if (number===4) return "Apr";
    if (number===5) return "May";
    if (number===6) return "Jun";
    if (number===7) return "Jul";
    if (number===8) return "Aug";
    if (number===9) return "Sep";
    if (number===10) return "Oct";
    if (number===11) return "Nov";
    if (number===12) return "Dec";
}
```

Comment: thanks for this yes i have less time to do this right now i am going to use what edrain said i hope it works.  but i definitely will try to work this out  some other time @ted thanks for your help cheers

Comment: no problem. If edrain's solution fixed the problem for you, or mine, please note them as "accepted", so people know.

Answer (score 0):

Best option to parse Dates objects is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

If you want to parse the date using a filter, you could install [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) module.

Then you can do something like this in your view (asuming that you assigned DepartureTime value to $scope.date):

```
<span>{{ date | amParse:'DD MMM HH:mm' }}</span>
```

Hope it helps1

Comment: can it be done with the split functions like we do in java script ?

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a very good option for parsing dates. If you want to use it in your project, then the solution is very simple, like the below one:

```
moment(DepartureTime).format('DD MMM h:m');
e.g. moment('2016-04-12T16:30:00.000+01:00').format('DD MMM h:m');
```

You can choose its angular version. You may check out [angular-momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs).